# Difference between object and reference in java with code?

Tags: java

```
public class TestVO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VO vo1 = new VO();
        VO vo2 = new VO();
        VO vo3;
        VO vo4 = new VO();

        vo1.setName("Sourav");
        vo2.setName("Anil");

        vo3 = vo1;
        vo4 = vo1;

        System.out.println(" " + vo4.getName());

        vo1.setName("Abhishek.");

        System.out.println(vo1.getName() + "  " + vo2.getName() + " " + vo3.getName() + " " + vo4.getName());
    }
}
```

--OUTPUT is:---

```
Sourav

Abhishek.  Anil Abhishek. Abhishek.
```

VO is a simple class contain  **String name** and contain **getter** and **setter**.

In the first **System.out.println** **vo4.getName()**  print : **Sourav** ok.It's fine.

But in the 2nd **System.out.println** **vo4.getName()** print : **Abhishek.**

My Question is why 2nd print is **Abhishek.**. I have kept a copy of vo1 object in vo4 object not a reference. That means it create a new memory. vo1 and vo4 are different.Then why vo4.getName is changed in the 2nd time. I am setting the vo1 object but vo4 is automatically changed. Why it is happening ??

Comment: You create objects with the new keyword, = transfers the **reference** of that object into the variable, equally var1=var2 copies the reference **not the object**

Answer (score 26):

> I have kept a copy of vo1 object in vo4 object not a reference.

No, you've pointed the variables `vo1` and `vo4` at the **same** object, like this:

```
+-----+
| vo1 |--------\
+-----+         \    +----------------+
                 --->| (object)       |
+-----+         /    | name = Abishek |
| vo4 |--------/     +----------------+
+-----+
```

Let's follow the code through:

```
VO vo1 = new VO();
```

Gives us:

```
+-----+              +----------------+
| vo1 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = null    |
                     +----------------+
```

Then:

```
VO vo2 = new VO();
```

Now we have:

```
+-----+              +----------------+
| vo1 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = null    |
                     +----------------+

+-----+              +----------------+
| vo2 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = null    |
                     +----------------+
```

Then:

```
VO vo3;
```

...which just creates `vo3` with `null` (not pointing at any object).

Then:

```
VO vo4 = new VO();
```

So we have:

```
+-----+              +----------------+
| vo1 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = null    |
                     +----------------+

+-----+              +----------------+
| vo2 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = null    |
                     +----------------+
+-----+
| vo3 | (is null)
+-----+

+-----+              +----------------+
| vo4 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = null    |
                     +----------------+
```

Now:

```
vo1.setName("Sourav");
vo2.setName("Anil");
```

Gives us:

```
+-----+              +----------------+
| vo1 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = Sourav  |     *** change is here ***
                     +----------------+

+-----+              +----------------+
| vo2 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = Anil    |     *** and here ***
                     +----------------+
+-----+
| vo3 | (is null)
+-----+

+-----+              +----------------+
| vo4 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = null    |
                     +----------------+
```

Here's where things get interesting:

```
vo3 = vo1;
vo4 = vo1;
```

That points `vo3` at the same object `vo1` points to, and points `vo4` at that object as well, *releasing* the object `vo4` used to point to (which becomes eligible for garbage collection). Giving us:

```
+-----+
| vo1 |----\
+-----+     \
             \
+-----+       \      +----------------+
| vo3 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+       /      | name = Sourav  |
             /       +----------------+
+-----+     /
| vo4 |----/
+-----+

+-----+              +----------------+
| vo2 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = Anil    |
                     +----------------+
```

Now

```
System.out.println(" " + vo4.getName());
```

...gives us "Sourav" as you'd expect.

Then

```
 vo1.setName("Abhishek.");
```

...changes the object that `vo1`, `vo3`, and `vo4` are all pointing to:

```
+-----+
| vo1 |----\
+-----+     \
             \
+-----+       \      +----------------+
| vo3 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+       /      | name = Abishek |
             /       +----------------+
+-----+     /
| vo4 |----/
+-----+

+-----+              +----------------+
| vo2 |------------->| (object)       |
+-----+              | name = Anil    |
                     +----------------+
```

...and so `getName()` on `vo1`, `vo3`, or `vo4` will give you "Abishek."

Comment: @GrahamSmith: Love me some ASCII-art. I probably should have used http://yuml.me/, though. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Because both vo1 and vo4 are referring to the same object.

Below assignment makes vo4 to refer to an object that is referenced by vo1.

```
vo4 = vo1;
```

And hence, any changes made to referring object by any of the reference(be it vo1 or vo4) will be reflect to the same object.

So if you change say vo4.setName("xyz"), its going to change the object which is referred by vo4 but actually vo1 is also referring to the same object. So changes are made at one memory location allocated for ONE object which is being REFERENCED by many references( in this case vo1 and vo4).

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the same object reference to `vo1` and `vo4` .

```
vo4 = vo1;
```

Now both the reference variables are pointing to the same object.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Object is an entity which will store actual value for the fields defined within it.Object will get created on memory using `new` keyword and reference will be returned to reference variable.Reference variable is not an object.
So in your example `new VO()` will create object on heap memory and `VO1` will have reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

when you do `vo4 = vo1;` you simply copy `vo1` by refernce to `vo4`, in other terms you do a pointer assignment so they both assign to the same location in memory which results if `vo1` changes it will also affect `vo4` too, as in the result you see

Answer (score 0):

Everything in java except for the basic data types is a pointer. After creating `vo4` you set it equal to `vo1`. Now `vo4` points to `v01`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `vo4 = vo1`, it means the reference variable `vo4` is referring to the object referred by `vo1`. So both `vo1` and `vo4` will refer to same object

Read the first part of this tutorial. You don't need to go till the end as it is about garbage collection but it explains in good detail how refrences are assigned to objects and how are they chagned.

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/22/how-do-objects-become-eligible-for-garbage-collection/

Answer (score 0):

I have to prepare the following picture:
as you see vo1, Vo3, Vo4 point to the same object

[image]

Comment: Simplest diagram to understand.Thankx.

Comment: @ABasak: Except the labels are backward. The variables are on the stack, not the heap; the objects are in the heap, not the stack.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: Thank you very much for your comment, I corrected this error