# How to make object in java. I have Test Class but not constructor

Tags: java, object

I'm very confused about object:

I'm creating a object Here is my Test Class :
**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

     public static void main(String[] argc){
      Test obj; //1. ---> here object is created
      Test obj = new Test(); //2. --> or here object is created
      }
    }
```

Please

Comment: In line 1 you didnt create a object,only declare a reference,In line 2 you create a Test object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610088/difference-between-object-and-reference-in-java-with-code  you can look this link.Different reference and object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html), Object creation as three parts:

1. **Declaration**: To declare obj variable:

`Test obj;`

It simply declares a variable. For primitive variables, this declaration also reserves the proper amount of memory, but for reference variables it does not create object.

2. **Instantiation**: To instantiate obj variable:

   `Test obj = new Test();`

Operator `new` is required to allocate memroy for the obj and returning the reference to that memory.  The `new` operator also invokes the object constructor.

3. **Initialization**: To initialization obj variable it's constructor needs to be called. In Java, constructor is invoked by the `new` operator. In other languages e.g. C, C++ when you instantiate any variable using `malloc` it doesn't call constructor, which needs to be called explicitly. However `new` operator behaves similar.

Answer (score 2):

Every class without a self-coded constructor has the so called `default contructor`. This one is invisible and would have this code:

```
public Test() {

}
```

In line 1 you only declare a variable of type `Test`.
In line 2 you actually create an object of type `Test` and assign it to the variable `obj`.

Comment: I am define this `Test obj` called object

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: first line is object or second line object

Comment: Only in the second line you create your `Test` object

Answer (score 1):

The first version

```
Test obj;
```

just declares `obj` value, not creates it. You can use it later in your code. Currently it contains `null` pointer, or points to nothing.

In the second version

```
Test obj = new Test();
```

combines declaration (`Test obj`), creation (`new Test()` part) and assignment (`=`).